# scanf in a loop to read a char x86 masm

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, msvcrt

I am trying to read a character in a loop from keyboard until I pass '&'. The code seems to work if I try to read numbers and with format "%d", but not with "%c".

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall

includelib msvcrt.lib
extern exit:proc
extern printf:proc
extern scanf:proc

public start

.data
    string db 100 dup(?)
    msg db "Read until &",13,10,0
    format db "%c",0
    caracter db " "

.code
start:
    mov ecx,3
    mov esi,0
    reader:
        push ecx

        push offset msg
        call printf 
        add esp,4

        pop edx
        push edx

        push offset caracter
        push offset format
        call scanf 
        add esp,8


        pop ecx
    loop reader

    exit_from:



push 0
call exit
end start
```

The result is something like this:

```
Read until &
a
Read until &
Read until &
b
exit
```

What am I missing, and how do I fix it?

Comment: What exactly do you think is a problem?  Looks like everything is working as expected.  `%c` doesn't skip whitespace (including newline), so `a<return>b<return>` scans 3 characters.  You can use `" %c"` to skip leading whitespace.

Comment: " %c" works. Thanks a lot!